# Get all Mondays from a particular timezone in SQLITE where the Date Text are stored in UTC Timezone

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a Date column (Text as sqlite does not store dates) called Dates. These dates are stored in UTC. I have a timezone 'Europe/London' (this can be changed, making localtime not viable here) and I want to get all Mondays with this timezone. However, if I just do select with `where strftime('%w', Dates)=01` it's is only getting the Mondays from UTC time. I want to get Mondays from 'Europe/London' or any other timezone. How can I do this?

Edit: Clarified my question and that localtime will not work here

Comment: Have you tried using the `localtime` modifier?? `strftime('%w', Dates, 'localtime')`; assuming that local time on the machine is Europe/London

Comment: I do not want to do that as if I wanted a different timezone, this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Values in `local_ts` and `local_day_of_week` depends on system settings

```
with cte_utc_dates (utc_ts) as (
values ('2022-11-22 00:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 01:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 02:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 03:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 04:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 05:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 06:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 07:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 08:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 09:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 10:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 11:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 12:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 13:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 14:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 15:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 16:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 17:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 18:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 19:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 20:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 21:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 22:00:00'),
       ('2022-11-22 03:00:00'))
select utc_ts,
       strftime('%w', utc_ts)                        as utc_day_of_week,
       datetime(utc_ts, 'localtime')                 as local_ts,
       strftime('%w', datetime(utc_ts, 'localtime')) as local_day_of_week
  from cte_utc_dates;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I am looking to do it without localtime. Is that possible?

Comment: @JacobyWilliams You may need to do it outside of SQLite such as http://timezonedb.com/references/convert-time-zone.